# Let R be an integral domain. Show that if the only ideals in R are {0} and R itself, R must be a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that if (x)={0} then the if 0=r0 such that r belongs to R therefor it's a field.
Most likely I'm wrong but I need help with the second part if the ideal is R

Comment: Does $R$ contain a multiplicative identity? (I'm guessing so, because the question wouldn't make much sense otherwise.)

Comment: Ya, that's included in the def of integral domain, a commutative ring with identity..etc

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if every nonzero ideal of $R$ is $R$, then every nonzero ideal contains $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ with unit.

Let $0\neq x\in R$ then $ 0\neq ( x)$ is an ideal of $R$ , hence $(x)=R$ so there exists $a$ in $R$ sush that $ax=1$.